# Primefaces commandButton only working on first entry of a carousel component

Tags: jsf, primefaces, carousel

I use a Primefaces carousel component to display a list of items. What i would like to do is show a commandButton on every carousel item which triggers a method on the bean to confirm or decline the entry.

Now it works only for the first entry of the carousel. Clicking on another entry does not invoke the action confirmResource. I guess it has something to do with the IDs but i can't figure it out.

Here's the form:

```
<h:form id="form" prependId="false">
<p:carousel id="resourceCarousel" value="#{resourceRatingBean.resourceProposalList}" var="var" rows="1" itemStyle="width:500px; height: 400px; text-align:center;" circular="true">
    <p:column>

        <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="3">
            <p:graphicImage value="/cache/images/#{var.imagePath}" width="100"/>
            <h:outputText value="#{var.imagePath}" />
            <h:outputText value="#{var.name}" />
            <h:outputText value="#{var.description}" />
        </h:panelGrid>

        <p:commandButton value="confirm" action="#{resourceRatingBean.confirmResource}" process="@this">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{var}" target="#{resourceRatingBean.ratedResource}" />
        </p:commandButton>

    </p:column>
</p:carousel>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two likely problems here:

1. The `process="@this"` is likely an issue as this will only invoke the process of the invoke the action of the commandButton and not the changes in the carousel component.  Try setting this attribute to `resourceCarousel` or `@form` instead.
2. If you are still having issues and using JSF 2 + EL 2.2, then instead of depending on `setPropertyActionListener` to set the value of a managed property, then instead you can pass the argument `var` to an `actionListener` method through an EL expression.

Here is an example:

```
<p:commandButton value="confirm" actionListener="${resourceRatingBean.confirmResourceListener(var)}"
    this="resourceCarousel" />
```

Comment: Setting process="@form" and it works like a charm! Thought I had tried that before ;-)..thanks for your solution!